# English Date to Arabic Text using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert from `English Date` to `Arabic Text` using javascript

Let's say if i give **22/08/2019** then it needs to be converted to Arabic Text format( Like in english it's twenty second august two thousand ninteen). So similar thing i am looking to generate the Date String in Arabic.

Comment: There is no javascript built-in function to convert numbers or dates to Arabic String. I can develop that very easily.

Comment: In your example: the Arabic text output should be: `الثاني والعشرون من شهر أغسطس سنة ألفان وتسع عشرة`

Answer (score 1):

strange this only works on a browser. run the snippet below or follow the instructions below you'll be fine.

```js
var event = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));
var options = {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric'
};

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('ar-EG', options));
```

this should work although this will work on your browser

1. go to chrome open a tab
2. press fn + f12,  (windows) not sure about mac
3. go to console

paste the above code line by line, press enter.
you should get the output below

```js
// expected output: الخميس، ٢٠ ديسمبر، ٢٠١٢
```

Comment: This solution does not convert the digits of the month and year to Arabic text as they remain as digits. The output requested by the OP in Arabic text should be as follows: `الثاني والعشرون من شهر أغسطس سنة ألفان وتسع عشرة`